# Bazel select() based on build config

Tags: bazel

I am trying to provide some preprocessor definitions at compile time based on whether the user runs `bazel test` or `bazel build`.

Specifically, I want to have a conditional dependency of a `cc_library.deps` and a conditional definition in `cc_library.defines`.

I found that `select()` is the way to go but I cannot figure out how to know what action the user runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to detect the current command (`build` vs `test`) using `select()`, but I think you can achieve something similar with [custom keys](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html#custom-keys).

You could define a `config_setting` block like the following:

```py
# BUILD
config_setting(
  name = "custom",
  values = {
    "define": "enable_my_flag=true"
  }
)
```

and use it in your library to control the `defines`:

```py
# BUILD - continued
cc_library(
  name = "mylib",
  hdrs = ["mylib.h"],
  srcs = ["mylib.cc"],
  defines = select({
    ":custom": ["MY_FLAG"],
    "//conditions:default": [],
  })
)
```

Now building the library using `bazel build :mylib` will result in the default case - no defines to be present, but if you build using `bazel build :mylib --define enable_my_flag=true` then the other branch will be selected and `MY_FLAG` will be defined.

This can be easily extended to the test case, for example by adding the `--define` to your `.bazelrc`:

```py
# .bazelrc
test --define enable_my_flag=true
```

Now every time you run `bazel test :mylib_test` the `define` flag will be appended and the library will be built with `MY_FLAG` defined.

Out of curiosity why do you want to run the test on a library built with a different set of defines/dependencies? That might defeat the purpose of the test since in the end you're testing something different from the library you're going to use.

Comment: It is not exactly what I was hoping for, but solves my problem for now. Thank you!

Comment: I find this example very confusing -- the name of the custom config setting is `custom`, but that doesn't appear anywhere on the command line. And the definition of it is to establish a key value pair mapping `define` to `enable_my_flag=true`. It's unclear if `define` is a bazel concept, or how it exposes the C concept of `#define`. But for some reason the key we used for the setting is what we put on the command line... and we are setting it to a string value that looks like setting a variable, but I guess is just a string?

Comment: "It's unclear if define is a bazel concept, or how it exposes the C concept of #define" I believe Bazel's `--define` was originally exactly for defining things in C/C++, but the ways it is used has grown over time. See https://bazel.build/reference/be/make-variables

Comment: "the name of the custom config setting is custom, but that doesn't appear anywhere on the command line" -- `custom` is the config_setting used in the `select()`, and `custom` is "activated" / "enabled" when the flags in `values` are specified on the command line, in this case when there is a `--define` with the value `enable_my_flag=true`. Separately, `--define enable_my_flag=true` on the command line sets the "make" variable `enable_my_flag` to `true`. Since `cc_library.defines` accepts make variables, you could similarly do `":custom": ["MY_FLAG=$(MY_FLAG)"]` and set `--define MY_FLAG=foo`

Comment: I find config settings confusing too. @ahumesky, what if we set the config settings values to {"define_custom": "enable_my_flag=true"} ? How is the config now enabled from command line, with --define_custom = enable_my_flag=true ?

Comment: `values` in `config_setting` only recognizes built-in flags (i.e. flags that are defined in bazel itself). To define a new flag you'd use Starlark flags and `flag_values` in `config_setting`. See https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes#custom-flags