# Add specific copts when building libraries for tests

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a c++ library and tests attached to it. In order for the tests to pass I need to pass a special copt(define), however I want to pass it only when compiling for the tests.

I want it to be as seamless as possible, that whenever I'm compiling the tests it will pass the define to the relevant sources, and when not compiling for the tests it won't.

Thought about passing a transition through cc_test that will change a configuration which will result in the addition of the define to the cc_compilation_context. However this requires attaching a transition to cc_test which as far as I know is not possible.

Have any ideas what to do?

Comment: Check out this [How-to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383035/bazel-select-based-on-build-config/57396491#57396491) to a similar question. Incl. the last paragraph that does ask a very relevant question / hint why you may not want to do that.. ;)

Comment: I would generally avoid what you are attempting. Essentially what this will end up doing is completely invalidating your cache between build/tests. There are other methods for creating code that is only used in testing. This typically involves refactoring your code into two portions your library and testing helpers. This also helps by ensuring there is some seperation of concerns between your library and your test-harnesses.