# Bazel conditional compile a C++ library if a flag is set (when building the library or one of targets that use it)

Tags: c++, bazel, conditional-compilation, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I'm trying to conditionally compile a C++ library with bazel depending on if a particular flag is set when building/running one of the target that use the library or the library itself.

My library has something like:

```cpp
//libraryheader.hpp
#ifdef MY_MACRO
#pragma message("MY_MACRO is defined")
//do something
#else
// do something else
#endif
```

Here's what I've tried. The BUILD file looks something like

```
#BUILD
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "string_flag")

use_the_feature_macro = string_flag(
    name = "use_the_feature",
    build_setting_default = "",
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_library",
    testonly = True,
    srcs = [
        "somefile.cpp",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "libraryheader.hpp",
    ],
    copts = select({
        ":use_the_feature_macro": ["-DMY_MACRO"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
    data = [],
    visibility = ["//path/to/smth:__subpackages__"],
    deps = [
        "//path/to/smth:targ1",
        ...
    ],
)
```

When trying to build with a command like `bazel build --use_the_feature //path/to:my_library` I keep getting errors about the unrecognized option. I've also tried with `bazel build --//path/to:use_feature //path/to:my_library but it doesn't work. Still unrecognised option

> ERROR: --use_the_feature :: Unrecognized option: --use_the_feature

What I whish to achieve is to be able to conditionally compile the library both when compiling the library by itself or when compiling a target that uses the library. For now, looking at the bazel documentation I don't know if I should use string_flag or config_setting and the examples on their [github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/d18ce42623f136616e9512d713a47c33f9ad6a58/configurations) are quite difficult to understand.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383035/bazel-select-based-on-build-config/57396491#57396491 for a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is a [`config_setting`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#config_setting) that depends on the flag value, which then you can use in your `select()`.

Here is a complete working example:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:common_settings.bzl", "string_flag")

config_setting(
    name = "feature_is_used",
    flag_values = {
        ":use_the_feature": "yes",
    },
)

string_flag(
    name = "use_the_feature",
    build_setting_default = "",
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_library",
    testonly = True,
    srcs = ["somefile.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["libraryheader.hpp"],
    copts = select({
        ":feature_is_used": ["-DMY_MACRO"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```

Then you can use `bazel build --//:use_the_feature=yes :my_library` to build with the macro. There's nothing special about the word "yes", you can enable macros one-by-one this way, or you can switch to using a [`bool_flag`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/docs/common_settings_doc.md#bool_flag) if you want a single toggle.

---

For completeness, here are the remaining files needed for the build:

- `MODULE.bazel`

```
bazel_dep(name = "bazel_skylib", version = "1.5.0")
```

- `libraryheader.hpp`

```cpp
// libraryheader.hpp
#ifdef MY_MACRO
#pragma message("MY_MACRO is defined")
// do something
#else
// do something else
#endif
```

- `somefile.cpp` can be empty.

Comment: It works! Now I have a question though. What if I'm compiling a target that has this library as a dependency? Could I pass the --//:use_the_feature=yes to the targets I want to have the version of the library with the macro set and not use it for other targets?

Comment: To do that, you can either have two targets, e.g. `my_library` and `my_library_with_feature`, and then depend on the one with feature where you want, or you can use [a transition](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/transition) to transition to the config where the build setting is set. Having two targets is definitely the simplest way to go.